# How can I easily enable/disable all modules in IIS?

Tags: iis

In [this serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/258759), the author make the following comment:

> As a test **I pulled out *every* module in IIS** so that it didn't even have a static page handler, and it still displayed the 400 error message.

I would like to do the same thing: disable all modules in IIS to perform a test, then re-enable all modules after my test. I can remove each module one-by-one, but that is tedious, and then I need to manually add them all back.

Is there an easy way to disable/enable all modules in IIS?

Comment: Open `applicationHost.config` and edit it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lex pointed me in the right direction in the comments: the `applicationHost.config` file.

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/introduction-to-applicationhostconfig), this file is located at `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config`.

That file appears to have two lists of modules: `globalModules` and `modules`. I was able to quickly enable/disable modules by simply commenting/uncommenting modules in the `modules` list.

Comment: please click "Accept Answer" that can help more people solve the same problem.

Comment: There is a waiting period since it is my own answer. I will accept tomorrow.